# find and recurse

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a folder structure `d:\domains\<domain>\folder1\folder2\folderx`

There are maybe 20 `<domain>` folders, with differing levels of folders below them.

I want to search all folders for `.php` files, and just print the unique `<domain>` folders where they exit.

So for example, if there are files found in

- d:\domains\domain1.com\test\test
- d:\domains\domain2.com\test\test
- d:\domains\domain2.com\test\help

I just want `domain1.com,domain2.com` to be printed. It needs to work in PowerShell v2.

I have the following, but it only prints the first domain?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path @(Get-ChildItem -Path D:\domains | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer})[1].FullName -Recurse *.php |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: `needs to work in PS2` assuming this is Powershell v2?

Comment: yea sorry, powershell 2

Comment: is "_"the unique `<domain>` folders"_ always the "lowest" folder within the search root?

Comment: Not a full answer, but to help you in future... You're only getting a single file as you are selecting the second file from your search by including `[1]` (first file is `[0]`), removing this will return a list of all the php files in your search. Useful post on [array help for powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/12/05/learn-simple-ways-to-handle-windows-powershell-arrays/)

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the domain folders, then filter for those of them that contain .php files.

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\domains' | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Filter '*.php' -Recurse)
}
```

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can use the `-Directory` switch instead of checking for `$_.PSIsContainer`:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\domains' -Directory | Where-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Filter '*.php' -Recurse
}
```

Select the `Name` property from the output if you want just the folder/domain names:

```
... | Select-Object -Expand Name
```